# C# HttpClient Cookie and Session ID question

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient

went through a bit of reading material, and found for processes that only require input into simple forms, rather then browser automation, I was hearing about making requests and posts to the server with the information it expects with HTTPrequests. I figured I would give it a shot!

I will try to get straight to the point here:

```
class Program
 {     
   private static System.Net.CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    private static HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect = true,
        UseCookies = true,
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer
    };
```

So that is me attempting to get the Http client to use throughout the program. And when I get to my first login screen (I used fiddler to see what the form needed to post), I make a successful login with the post.

I will show you the post method:

```
         async static void PostRequest(string strUrl, 
          IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries)
    {
        HttpContent q = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(strUrl, q);

        HttpContent content = response.Content;
        string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Console.WriteLine(myContent);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        Console.WriteLine(myContent);
        response.Dispose();

    }
```

My issue here, the next post I attempt to do is another form after you have been logged in. I again used Fiddler to figure out what the server was expected, and posted it to the appropriate URL, but when I print each step of the process, its almost like it does not know the session or something. Fiddler showed me the cookie and session, and I thought it was being captured with the container and then it could be used throughout the rest of the program as I request/post to pages on the server.

Am I missing anything? You all won't be able to go the the actual webpage, but I can explain what fiddler is showing under the cookies tab: Says the request sent 2685 bytes of cookie data then a huge set of random letters and numbers and a few values that look specific to my login, then I also see another random set of numbers and letters that are called session id.

So to sum up what my question is, am I misunderstanding what CookieContainer does? My assumption was throughout all the requests or posts I make with this HttpClient it would know it was the session from my initial login.

Thoughts, ideas, links I may not have yet discovered, are all appreciated :).

Thanks guys!

Comment: CookieContainer is tied to one request/response. You'll need to retrieve auth cookies from the login response and re-add them into other requests. Best way here, IMHO, would be to create a `ServiceCliente` that keeps track and auto-adds this cookie on every request, instead of doing this manually every single time.

Comment: Understood, and when you say that, you mean the value that I was able to print into the console that begins with: "set-cookie", so the value after that (the long string of characters) is what I want?

Comment: Anderson, you should answer this so I can pick it. I was able to get the cookie and session ID as you said and in that manner.

Comment: Aswered so you can mark as solved. After that I'll remove this comment :)

Comment: Thanks man! Really helped me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem you're facing is that cookies are automatic from the browser perspective but they are bound to a round-trip to/from the server.

So, when you're outside the browser (from the .NET perspective), CookieContainer will be tied to the request (and its response) and nothing more.

To achive what you want, you'll need to retrieve cookie values form the response, store them somewhere else and re-insert them in the next request.

You'll find useful to create some sort of `Client` to encapsulate that and automatically attach cookies from previous response to the next request so you don't have to do that manually every single time.

Comment: Can you provide some reference about the solution you described ?

Comment: @Muflix Maybe [this](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/395) can help.